# Can any user get access of the internal java files of a package file?

Tags: android, api

I'm developing an android app and in the app, I am using async task to download the source code of some URLs...these url's are from the internal tool of my website which cannot be used by anyone else other than me...i want to know if any user can find out that the app is requesting data from a url of my site...

Comment: You should share what code you've written to show how you attempted to solve the problem which didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anybody with your apk file can decode in sites as follow or similars

- [javadecompilers](https://www.javadecompilers.com/apk)
- [apkdecompilers](https://www.apkdecompilers.com)

And do see your url of your site